# how to delete users including roles and users from AspnetRoleUsers

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I am making a project using `asp.net core 3.1` and I can't find the right source of deleting users including roles in `Asp.net core 3.1` using Web.api

This is the code I have tried but seems like not appropriate but haven't tried yet. Do you have any ideas of how to realize that? 
I want to appropriately check the error using Web Api functions such as statuscode or any error messages to the frontend.

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteUser(string id)
{


    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    var rolesForUser = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user); 
    if (rolesForUser.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in rolesForUser.ToList())
        {
            // item should be the name of the role
            var result = await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, item);
        }
    }

    await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);  
    return OkResult(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to loop the roles and delete , you can use `RemoveFromRolesAsync` :

```
public virtual Task<IdentityResult> RemoveFromRolesAsync(TUser user, IEnumerable<string> roles);
```

And each operation will return `IdentityResult` which could be used to check the operation status :

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    try
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        var roles= await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);  

        var result =  await _userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user, roles);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var resultdelete = await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return Ok();
            }
            else
            {
                List<string> errors = new List<string>();
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    errors.Add(error.Description);
                }
                return BadRequest(errors);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            List<string> errors = new List<string>();
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                errors.Add(error.Description);
            }
            return BadRequest(errors);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        List<string> errors = new List<string>() { exception.Message };
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, errors);
    }
}
```

But use database stored procedures with transaction is always a good choice .